# Elmah - don't log full stack trace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I would like to control the Elmah log - specifically I would like to not record the full stack trace. Is it possible to control what Emlah actually logs? I know you can filter the type of errors, but what about the contents of the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELMAH doesn't offer a hook to allow you to modify the message before storing it. The only ways to do this is to modify the ELMAH source (not recommended) or to create a new error log, inheriting from the error logger you are currently using:

```
public class MySqlErrorLog : SqlErrorLog
{
    public MySqlErrorLog(IDictionary config) : base(config)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override string Log(Error error)
    {
        error.Detail = string.Empty;

        return base.Log(error);
    }
}
```